# Notes value practise without metronome

Tags: theory, piano, technique, scales

When I practise scales or chords, amongst other things, I usually do it using whole notes then half notes then quarters ..etc...
I use a metronome all the time but wanted to know if there are other ways?

Do mantras, songs or anything else exists to actually give you the right rhythm without a metronome?

Comment: What instrument(s)?  If piano, you can start with quarters and go faster from there.  I don't know of any mantras etc.

Answer (score 2):

I use a variant of [this](http://www.takadimi.net/documents/Takadimi%20short%20guide%20for%20Web.pdf). Rhythmic solfege. It is very effective. I never really got a sense of reading rhythms with numbers and as a result I had to rely heavily on memorization. One day I met a piano teacher who used this method (with different syllables) and I was very quickly able to overcome my hurdles. You are right ot one to learn how to practice these things without a metronome since you really can't always rely on one to follow you through ritardandos and tempo changes.

Don't try to learn the syllables all at once since you would be compounding learning the rhythms and the syllables. Just learn one set of syllables and get used to it it and then keep adding as saying the syllables become automatic.

EDIT: The variant of rhytmic solfege originally posted is called takadimi. I suspect that there are several other names based on the syllables used. Takadimi is just the first google result.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I have struggled as you have and oddly, my metronome practise is always"approximate" I do better when I listen to the rhythm in my head but I needed a support. I'll try this for sure or a variant I might make up

Comment: @xerotolerant  - You might want to put the name of the method, Takadimi, in your answer in case your link goes down, make it easier for people to look it up.

Comment: Glad i could help. Also I'll add the name. I'm trying to remember what my piano teacher called it because it def wasn't takadimi. Today is the first time I came across that. Another teacher called it called it rhythmic solfege which is what I called it in the answer.

Comment: I've always heard it as Takadimi, so probably a common usage.

Comment: Something similar to 1e&a 2e&a 3e&a 4e&a, which works too. And helps to say which actual beat one is on.